# Javascript XML Access

Tags: xml, file, get, xmlhttprequest, send

I am trying to access my first XML file, but am stumped on how this isn't working. Do I need to run a server for it to work? I'm running this on Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Starter File</title>
    <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "motd.xml", "false");
        xhttp.send();

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.getElementsByTagName("daily")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

And here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<messages>
  <daily>Today is Sunday.</daily>
  <daily>Today is Monday.</daily>
  <daily>Today is Tuesday.</daily>
  <daily>Today is Wednesday.</daily>
  <daily>Today is Thursday.</daily>
  <daily>Today is Friday.</daily>
  <daily>Today is Saturday.</daily>
</messages>
```

Answer (score 0):

## You are making an asynchronous request

> ```
> xhttp.open("GET", "motd.xml", "false");
> ```

The third argument to `open` is a *boolean*. If it is `true` (the default) you make an asynchronous request. If it is `false` (which is **deprecated**) then you make a synchronous request.

The *string* `"false"` is equivalent to the boolean `true`.

You are trying to read the response before it has arrived.

If you changed that to `false` then you would be trying to assign the results to the `innerHTML` of the paragraph before that paragraph existed.

### The fix

- Use an event listener to wait for the XML to load before you try to use it
- Move the JavaScript so it runs after the paragraph you are trying to modify exists

## You are trying to treat the XHR object as an HTML document

`XMLHttpRequest` is an API for making HTTP requests. It is not an XML document. You can't call `getElementsByTagName` on it. You have to read the response in XML format (`xhr.responseXML`) and call the method on that.

Such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Starter File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "motd.xml");
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.addEventListener("load", function () {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("daily")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

## The other problem

> Do I need to run a server for it to work? I'm running this on Chrome.

Yes. Chrome does not allow XMLHttpRequest access to local files for security reasons. (This security policy varies between browsers, for instance, Firefox will allow access to files in the same directory as the HTML document).

Comment: Thank you for a very in depth response. I have made the changes to my code, and at one point just copy and pasted your modifications into my document. However it still doesn't work... even on a newly updated Firefox. Any suggestions? In the meantime I will try and get a local server program.

Comment: I have replaced my code with your code, and hosted it on a local xampp server... however it is still not working for me.

Comment: @NathanWonz — You had a third problem I didn't notice the first time around. Edited.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now. I started learning this XML Javascript from a book written in 2011. It told me completely different stuff so I've been stumbling through it... a lot can change in 5 years apparently. Switching to 2015 edition now hehe.